# How to install Ubuntu on Windows XP

Tags: 10.10, wubi

I want to install Ubuntu 10.10 version but I don't about that one. Sir Is the internet required to install ubuntu. Sir please tell me in detail and can I get boot disc freely from you by application

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is all internet dependant, though you don't need it to install it. The reason for that is its internet-based application dependencies solving and community support.

To get Ubuntu for free, you will have to download the image of the disk yourself. If you would like a pre-burned copy shipped, you can buy whichever you need here: http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17 , though that only allows you to get many copies at a time.

Oh, and also, a piece of advise: don't use wubi (the Ubuntu installer that installs Ubuntu from Windows) for anything important. It is good for trying out,  but bad for everything else.

A bit of personal experience from running on a computer with absolutely no internet: very, very difficult to work with. At least I could download the needed packages on my machine that does have internet, though that is very inefficient.

Comment: For offline package installation, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/974/6969)

Comment: Ubuntu is not "all internet dependent" any more than any other OS. You'll need internet access to *easily* install new programs and updates, just like any OS. WUBI is no longer supported and doesn't work at all with Windows8